# Code to disable page contents while loading and show a gif image

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me how to keep the whole page inactive while loading and showing an image? I have the following code to show the image but while page is loading all the contents are active.Here's the code below :

```
<body onLoad="init()">
  <div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:100%; text-align:center;top:300px;">
    <img src="https://bancore.com/images/vv/loading_smaller.gif" border=0 />
  </div>
  <script>
    var ld = (document.all);
    var ns4 = document.layers;
    var ns6 = document.getElementById && !document.all;
    var ie4 = document.all;
    if (ns4)
      ld = document.loading;
    else if (ns6)
      ld = document.getElementById("loading").style;
    else if (ie4)
      ld = document.all.loading.style;
    function init() {
      if (ns4) { 
        ld.visibility = "hidden";
      } else if (ns6 || ie4) ld.display = "none";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Here is the sample website : http://www.bancore.com/

See while loading the page is inactive.

Comment: It's because their picture element (`#loading` div) covers the whole page, so technically you can only click on that div and not on any page elements.

Answer (score 0):

On your #loading div you should use `height: 100%` instead of `top: 300px` because top only moves the element 300 pixels from the top, making the top 300 pixels of the page clickable.

If you need to move the image down 300px, you still need to keep the #loading div fixed to the top but you can set the top margin to the image to 300px. Like this:

```
<div id="loading" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height: 100%; text-align:center;">
    <img src="https://bancore.com/images/vv/loading_smaller.gif" border=0 style="margin-top:300px;">     
</div>
```

You should also avoid using inline styles, but simply set the CSS rules in your CSS file:

```
#loading {
    position:absolute;  
    width:100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    text-align:center;
}

#loading img {
    margin-top: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the idea in this case is create a 'mask' over your website, then remove it when `document is ready`.

create CSS :

```
   .loading { 
     position: fixed; // position fixed with height, width = 100% will take over your window
     width:100%;
     height: 100%;
     top : 0; 
     left : 0;
     text-align : center;
     background : #ccc;
     opacity : 0.5; // fade your page.
   }
   .loading img {
     // I'm not good at CSS, so you can find some attribute to center it
     //check my fiddle for style
    }
```

add to HTML :

```
<div id="loading" class="loading">
       <img src="https://bancore.com/images/vv/loading_smaller.gif" border=0>     
</div>
```

and Javascript jQuery document ready :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#loading').removeClass('loading'); // the `class` loading will be remove
})
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ywbgpwm8/2/)